# Camel netty c++ java integration

Tags: java, c++, apache-camel, netty

I've got a legacy code written in c++ that send and receive data via socket UDP on a port. I need this software inside an enterprise environment using Java as main technology and activeMQ queue as communication channels. My questions: is it possible to use apache camel-netty to do this? Is there any example I can use for this kind of goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Camel netty docs](http://camel.apache.org/netty.html) is well done and you should easily be up and running with sending and receiving UDP datagrams with Camel. If you want codesamples, you have a large set, which include sending and receiving UDP, in the [test cases for camel-netty](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/components/camel-netty/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/netty).

You should give camel-netty a spin and try it. The Camel developers have gone done hard work to make sure every aspect of camel-netty is well documented and thouroughly covered by test cases. If you have detailed questions regarding handling a specific aspect of UDP handling in Camel, that is not visibly covered by the documentation, return here to ask it and surely you will get some help.